# CSS not applying on form elements when loading php page in dialog jquery

Tags: php, jquery, css

So I have categories buttons on the website, when they are being clicked a jquery dialog will popup and the information being shown is returned from a php script depending on the category. This all works perfectly, but the stylesheet is not applying on the returned data (select menus, checkboxes etc..).

```
$$.ready(function() 
{
    var dlg=$('#product_dialog').dialog({
    resizable: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    hide: 'fade',
    width:350,
    height:275
 });


    $( "#bestelling_1" ).on("click", "#product_dialog_open", function(e) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        dlg.dialog('open');
        var id = 1;
        $('#product_dialog_test').html('Ogenblik geduld..');
        $.ajax({
          url: "scripts/load_product_dialog.php?id="+id
        }).done(function(data) {
          $('#product_dialog_test').html(data).trigger('create'); // display data
        });
  });
```

});

So it all works perfectly, the dialog being opened, loaded and such.. just the stylesheets that are being loaded from index.php in the head doesnt apply on this dynamic retrieved data.

Comment: Could you show your CSS?

Comment: There's no such thing as CSS "not applying". The answer is a lot more simple - none of your CSS rules match the elements in the dialog. You need to take a look at the classes (and parent classes - `._10`, `._50` etc) applied to the elements in your dialog, and ensure that they match the selectors you're defining in your stylesheet. Please also note that posting a link to a website won't help other people in the future who have the same question. The best way to make that happen is to create an **isolated** example by posting **all** the relevant code required to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should put more details about your DOM and stylesheet so we can
    trace the problem. There's a lot of things that can prevent the
    style to apply,

1. Make sure the css file is actually loaded , you can look it up in
       developer tools in your browser.
2. Make sure you have write css rule and it's containing the element you want to style. It can get overridden by another rule or a rule in third-party css file. You can also look this up in developer tools.
3. If you're new data are loaded into an iFrame it will not use any of
       the CSS rules in your page. You have to put the css rule into the page that iFrame loads.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Jquery UI or some similar framework? For a lot of those you need to reapply the attributes when dynamically adding elements.

For example, if I'm using JQuery UI and I add a buttone after page load. I need to run `$('button').button()` to apply the Jquery UI button attributes to it.

If that's not the case you need to add more detail to your question. Or create a jsFiddle with a minimally verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause. I had to initialize the plugins after loading the content.

Comment: It's ok to [answer your own question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) if none of the answers helped in resolving your problem and you found it yourself. It's even encouraged. My only suggestion is that you edit and provide a little more information, e.g. adding an example, and avoid adding "thank you".